# How to describe multipart-form-data in swagger @Operation?

Tags: java, swagger, springdoc

There is an endpoint with request body of type `MULTIPART-FORM-DATA`, with three fields:

1. "my-attachment" - `required` field of type `File`
2. "options" - `required` field of any type (`File` or `Text`)
3. "note" - `optional` field of type `Text`

What is a proper way to describe this request body in Springdoc (or Swagger v3) using java annotations?

*I supposed that `@Operation` is eligible for this, but cannot find any appropriate way to use it.*

`io.swagger.core.v3 - version 2.1.3`

Comment: Not really sure. But you can refer the issue at Springdoc https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/396

Answer (score 2):

Here a sample working code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload2", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String upload2(@RequestPart("my-attachment") MultipartFile myAttachment, @RequestPart("options") options options, Optional<Text> note) {
    return "Ok";
}
```